# How do you use curl within wordpress plugins?

Tags: php, curl, wordpress

I'm creating a wordpress plugin and I'm having trouble getting a cURL call to function correctly.

Lets say I have a page www.domain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=orders

Within the orders page I have a function that looks to see if a button was clicked and if so it needs to do a cURL call to the same page (www.domain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=orders&dosomething=true) to kick off a different function.  The reason I'm doing it this way is so I can have this cURL call be async.

I'm not getting any errors, but I'm also not getting any response back. If I change my url to google.com or example.com I will get a response.  Is there an authentication issue or something of that nature possibly?

My code looks something like this.. I'm using gets, echos, and not doing async just for the ease of testing.

```
if(isset($_POST['somebutton']))
{
    curlRequest("http://www.domain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=orders&dosomething=true");
}

if($_GET['dosomething'] == "true")
{
     echo("do something");
     exit;
}

function curlRequest($url) {
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    return($response); 
 }
```

Comment: You'll need to be able to route to your webserver via a loopback interface. Perhaps the web server has been configured to only listen on a 'public' IP, and not on a loopback address such as 127.0.0.1. I suggest trying something silly like `system("ping www.domain.com")` in a script to see if you can even route to the host 'internally'.

Comment: The curl works if I just go to the public part of the wordpress.. aka www.domain.com. But if I try to get to the admin (wp-admin) it doesn't give a response.

Comment: If you're looking for an asynchronous process, why not use ajax?  cURL *is* synchronous (ie your php script is going to block until cURL finishes) .

Comment: There is a way to may cURL not always be synchronous. I assumed I would get the same result by using AJAX, but it looks like that actually works.. Thanks

Comment: Related article: https://deliciousbrains.com/php-curl-how-wordpress-makes-http-requests/

Answer (score 15):

You're not supposed to use CURL in WordPress Plugins.

Instead use the wp_ function for issuing HTTP requests, e.g.

```
function wp_plugin_event_handler () {
    $url = 'http://your-end-point';  
    $foo = 'bar';
    $post_data = array(
         'email' => urlencode($foo));

    $result = wp_remote_post( $url, array( 'body' => $post_data ) );
}

add_action("wp_plugin_event", "wp_plugin_event_handler");
```

In the past I've run into issues where WordPress plugins event handlers would hang with CURL. Using the WP_ functions instead worked as expected.

Answer (score 3):

The admin section of the blog is password-protected, of course. You'll need to pass authentication data. Look up http authentication for details. Look specifically here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

You'll want to set the CURLOPT_USERPWD option and possibly CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH.